Snowflake JDBC Connection OAuth
I want to connect to snowflake database and it is using OAuth 2.0 how to connect with the database. I am able to connect initially (after running the springboot application) but after an hour its showing Oauth Token Expired.
I have registered my application using Azure AD and got client id, secret, scope, grantType for token generation
I am currently receiving the token using WebClient and passing it as a password to the Datasource connection. I know that the connection pool is not using the updated password how to configure it and is there any better way than WebClient or Am I missing anything? I am working on production is DriverManager a good approach or DataSource.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The OAuth access token is short-lived.
If the token is for the user, you can request a refresh token from the authorization server.
Using the grant type refresh_token where you renew the access token using the refresh token.
But if the access token is for the client, then in this case, the user is not present; hence, it is expected that a new access token will be requested when the current access token expires.
Hence if you have the access token generated for the user, you can use the refresh_token flow to renew the access token.
Refer to the following article which talks about the same.
Oauth External for the user.
